# sh -c: Unterminated quoted string error

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, escape-characters

I've spent hours trying to understand the following error.

My Script

```
CMD="sh -c 'echo \"a\"'"
$CMD
```

Error:

```
"a"': 1: "a"': Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

of course when I do `echo $CMD` and paste the result, it works as expected...

What is the cause of the error?

Edit:

I'm asking for an explanation not only a workaround. 
Therefore, I think the following link doesn't answer my question:
[Quoting in a function results in error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20349/quoting-in-a-function-results-in-error)

Answer (score 4):

That cannot work. When your shell performs word splitting, you will have **four** arguments:

```
sh
-c
'echo
"a"'
```

To accomplish this, you must use a bash array:

```
cmd=( sh -c 'echo "a"' )
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know aboud word splitting performed by the shell, I'm going to check this out!

Comment: See also [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Also, spend some time with the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: see my answer below! thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

The main error here is thinking that the single quotes around `'echo \"a\"'` would stop "word splitting" performed by the shell and pass `echo "a"` as a single argument to sh.

In this case, the single quotes are actually treated as "literal" not "syntactical" because they are included within the outer double quotes!

The following link helped me the most: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments